# Civilization VI Papal Primacy

Tags: civilization-6

The in-game description says:

> Type bonuses from city-states following your religion are 50% more powerful.

What does this mean? Exactly how does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://civ6.gamepedia.com/City-States) page here and from my own experience, each City State *type* has a bonus based on the number of envoys in the State.

**List of types** (Type, Color of City State, District type they build, 1 envoy bonus, 3 envoys, 6 envoys):

- Religious: White, Holy Site, +2 Faith in Capital, +2 Faith in every Holy Site district, Additional +2 Faith in every Holy Site district.
- Industrial: Brown, Industrial Zone, +2 Production in Capital when producing wonders, buildings and districts, +2 production in every Industrial Zone, Additional +2 Production in every Industrial Zone.
- Militaristic: Red, Encampment, +2 Production in the Capital when producing units, +2 Production in every Encampment district when producing units,  Additional +2 Production in every Encampment district when producing units.
- Scientific: Blue, Campus, +2 Science in Capital, +2 Science in every Campus district, Additional +2 Science in every Campus district.
- Trade: Yellow, Commercial Hub, +4 Gold in Capital, +4 Gold in every Commercial Hub district, Additional +4 Gold in every Commercial Hub district.
- Cultural: Purple, Theater Square, +2 Culture in the Capital, +2 Culture in every Theater Square district, Additional +2 Culture in every Theater Square district.

Each bonus will get a 50% increase to what it gives you. E.g if it gives you a +2 Production in every industrial zone when building certain things, you will now get a +3 bonus in each of those zones.

And as the belief states, this is only for city states that follow your religion.

Above information was edited. As PaulZ pointed out, this founder belief applies to type bonuses and not Suzerain unique bonuses.

Comment: So other than following my religion, I also need to be the city-state's Suzerain as well?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the opposite of what Papal Primacy does. The suzerain bonus is unique to each city-state, but this is not the Type bonus. The Type bonus is common to all city states of the same Type (religious, industrial, scientific, &c) and this is the bonus that is doubled by Papal Primacy.